# Why the 30 topics identified by Stanford Topic Modeling Toolkit so similar to each other?

Tags: machine-learning, stanford-nlp, text-analysis, lda

What can be the possible reasons why the 30 topics identified by Stanford
Topic Modeling Toolkit (it took ~4 hours) on the corpus of 19,500
articles (shared by Twitter users) so similar to each other? They
have pretty much the same terms, and frequencies => essentially, I
just have a single topic :)

The topics are identified can be found [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~asuleime/data/summary.txt)

I do standard prep of text docs before learning and inferring stages:
removing stop words, collapsing whitespaces, lowercasing everything,
etc.

Some of my params:

- numTopics = 30
- TermMinimumDocumentCountFilter = (10) ~>  // filter terms which occur in < 10 docs
- TermDynamicStopListFilter(30) ~> // filter out 30 most common terms
- DocumentMinimumLengthFilter(10) // take only docs with >= 10 terms
- topicSmoothing = SymmetricDirichletParams(0.01)
- termSmoothing = SymmetricDirichletParams(0.01)
- maxIterations = 10

Answer (score 1):

I'd say because your methodology seems to be flawed.  Raw word counts have intrinsic biases which are characteristics of the language, despite what topics are meant to be mined.

For example, words that have *no* impact on topic similarity, but are biasing your outcome:

```
very
well
good
```

While other words which are *purposefully* vague as they deal with references to other particulars

```
data
media
web
users
those
```

While other words are simply commonly used verbs or adverbs

```
need
going
think
know
want
```

Others are known industry brand names

```
apple
twitter
```

Until you can construct a verifiable model that word frequencies map to specific topics, all you have done is some data collection, some hand waving (instead of anti-hypothesis disproving), and a jump to the conclusion that your original premise is correct.

Restructure your classification to capture topics instead of words, and then build a model describing the distance between topics, and then attempt to show that within the 30 offered topics, there are really only 29 topics (or less) of "distance" great enough to stand on their own.

Because, it is all very well and good to collect data from users, but the need for data is secondary to the need for good data that is pertinent to being able to know what is wanted. (That sentence constructed purposefully, it has a high Standford Topic Modeling Toolkit "word count", but is likely not a *similar topic*)

Comment: If you manage to build such a model, odds are excellent that you can provide the same information in fewer courses, which means you are in a great position to write a "Distilled Standford Modelling Toolkit" guide.  Such things have value.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin. I think it's something to do with the way I'm using Stanford Topic Modeling Toolbox, so I refined my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217049/why-isnt-stanford-topic-modeling-toolbox-producing-lda-output-directory)